# Mix WebAPI and WCF with SimpleInjector

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I have created a WebApi application, which uses SimpleInjector.
Now a user of the API wants a WCF endpoint to consume it (for whatever reason).

To make things more simple for me, I want to just call the WebApi controller from inside the WCF service:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private MyApiController controller;

    public MyService(IMyInjection inject)
    {
        controller = new MyApiController(inject);
    }

    public int GetResult(string data)
    {
        return controller.GetResult(data);
    }
}
```

To make it work in WebApi, my controller currently uses an injection with a `WebApiRequestLifeStyle` lifestyle, and I have tried to "just add" [SimpleInjector WCF Integration](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wcfintegration.html) :

```
public static void LoadDependencyInjection()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    // some more registration

    // configure WCF to use SimpleInjector
    container.RegisterWcfServices(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    // verify
    container.Verify();

    // configure the global WebApi to use SimpleInjector
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    // configure WCF to use SimpleInjector
    SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer(container);
}
```

Obviously, the WCF service does not like the WebApi lifestyle, and throws an error when I try to call a method:

> The ITransferOrderRequest is registered as 'Web API Request' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of a Web API Request.

## Update

I have tried to create a second container with a different lifestyle:

```
public static void LoadDependencyInjection()
{
    // WebApi container
    var webApiContainer = CreateContainer(new WebApiRequestLifestyle(true));
    webApiContainer.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    webApiContainer.EnableHttpRequestMessageTracking(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    // WCF container
    var wcfContainer = CreateContainer(new WcfOperationLifestyle(true));
    wcfContainer.RegisterWcfServices(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    // verify
    webApiContainer.Verify();
    wcfContainer.Verify();

    // configure the global WebApi to use SimpleInjector
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(webApiContainer);

    // configure WCF to use SimpleInjector
    SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer(wcfContainer);
}

private static Container CreateContainer(ScopedLifestyle lifestyle)
{
    var container = new Container();

    // set the default lifestyle
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = lifestyle;

    // here I register a bunch of interfaces/instances using the Scoped lifestyle

    return container;
}
```

But the second call to `container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = lifestyle;` (using `WcfOperationLifestyle`) also changes the the default lifestyle of the first container! In this case, when I call my WebApi service I get the same kind of error, but in reverse:

> IMyStuff is registered as WCF operation lifestyle.

I have seen that there is a Hybrid lifestyle, but I have no idea how to detect whether it's currently a WCF or WebApi request...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an aversion to having WCF send the request over HTTP (using something like `WebClient`), instead of trying to new up a controller? I don't think your controller would get all of the benefits of the WebAPI request pipeline with the solution you are proposing.

Comment: Why don't you pass the `ScopedLifestyle` instance as parameter to your `LoadDependencyInjection()` method? This way each application can have its own scoped lifestyle (which is exactly what this feature is designed for).

Comment: @danludwig : You want that the WCF service calls the REST service over HTTP? I'm not very fond of this solution, to be honest.

Comment: @Steven : I tried to create 2 containers and change the `DefaultScopedLifestyle` but it seems (maybe it's a bug ?) that overriding the default on one container overwrites the other.

Comment: @cosmo0 why are you not fond of sending over HTTP? Do you also have an aversion to loose coupling? Are you aware of everything you are losing by just newing up a controller, as if this were a unit test?

Comment: Because it would mean I have to hard-write my HTTP routes, and it seems awfully inefficient to go through all the HTTP stack for something that should be fixed in another way.  
I'd rather extract my controller's code in a separate class, but it wouldn't fix the problem.  
No, I do not know very well WCF, so I don't know "what I loose by just newing up a controller".

Comment: @Steven it does not seem intuitive that changing the `DefaultScopedLifestyle` for one container would change it for both of them. Is that value stored statically, and if so, can it be explained why?

Comment: As far as I'm able to verify, there is no bug that causes DefaultScopedLifestyle instances to be shared across containers. If you are able to prove this with a failing unit test, please post it as issue on Simple Injector's Github project page.

Comment: @danludwig: there is no evidence of sharing if you look at the source code: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/master/src/SimpleInjector/ContainerOptions.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have no idea how to detect whether it's currently a WCF or WebApi request...

You can check whether the request is a WCF request by checking whether `OperationContext.Current != null`.

```
var lifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
    lifestyleSelector: () => OperationContext.Current != null,
    trueLifestyle: new WcfOperationLifestyle(true),
    falseLifestyle: new WebApiRequestLifestyle()
);
```

> I don't know "what I lose by just newing up a controller".

To clear up my suggestion in comments, I understand where you are coming from. It's still my opinion that you should consider doing this over HTTP before totally ruling it out. You can overcome the "hardwire routes" problem by making the URL part of the WCF project's app.config. There is some decent config transforms tooling you can use to generate different routes for different environments. Changing config to modify program behavior is loosely coupled, and highly cohesive.

It *is* a bit less efficient, but I would argue the cost may be justified if the *actual* additional latency is small enough. The things you lose are all of the WebAPI request pipeline benefits added to the controller, such as content negotiation, filters, etc. Since you didn't post any of that code and are OK with your decision, I assume you are really only after the `GetResults(string data)` method body with its scoped dependencies, and have no need for anything else.

However be aware that your decision creates a tighter coupling between the WCF service and the WebAPI controller than an HTTP network call would.

Comment: (about the edit): Ah! I think I understand "what I lose". Yes, it's a basic "data" webservice to be used internally (by other departments in the company), so I have no attribute except `[Route()]`... It is in fact my wish to couple the two, so that one has the same methods as the other. It's just 2 means to access the same thing.

Comment: @cosmo0 fair enough. As they say, "it's not a problem until it's a problem."